# How to watch virtual table on visual studio 2013

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base{
public:
    Base(){}
    virtual ~Base(){}
    virtual void f1(){}
    void f2(){ f3(); }
    virtual void f3(){ f1(); }
};

class Aba : public Base{
public:
    Aba(){}
    ~Aba(){}

    virtual void f1(){}
    virtual void f4(){ f3(); }
};

class Ben : public Aba{
public:
    Ben(){}
    ~Ben(){}
    virtual void f1(){ Aba::f2(); }
    void f3(){}
};

int main(){

    Base* b = new Base();;
    Aba* a = new Aba();
    Ben* s = new Ben();
}
```

I couldn't find a good explanation (that I can completely understand) on how the virtual table is build with any given code situation (I hope I explained my self well).
1) Is there a way to see the virtual tables on VS2013?

2) am I right on the following answer? -in this case, the virtual tables are:

```
Base-
Base::~Base()
Base::f1()
Base::f3()

Aba-
Aba::~Aba()
Aba::f1()
Base::f3()
Aba::f4()

Ben-
Ben::~Ben()
Ben::f1()
Ben::f3()
Aba::f4()
```

3) Is there any importance to the virtual methods order inside the virtual tables?

4) Does the fact that some of the methods call other virtual/non-virtual method effects the virtual tables?

Comment: Virtual tables on Windows are always in declaration order, this is what makes COM work with either C or C++.

Comment: The virtual table is build in the order of the written code?
if the virtual Dtor is written before the virtual f1(), the table order will be Dtor and then f1() and if the virtual f1() is written before the virtual Dtor,  the table order will be f1() and then Dtor?

Comment: Yes, and then derived classes follow the order of all base classes first, then any new virtual functions introduced in the derived class.